# How to show HTML from this array Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, dropdown

I'm new to Vue JS and I'm trying to pass an HTML table using this array, I have a dropdown where I select the option I want and then it shows it, but I can't figure out how can I put HTML in there, when I do it prints code instead. A little help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the HTML file:

```
        <div id="app">
            <div>
              {{pickedValue}}
            </div>
            <picker v-model="pickedValue"></picker>
        </div>
```

This is the JS file and I want to put an HTML table inside list:["c","d","e"]

```
  console.clear()

Vue.component("picker",{
  props:["value"],
  data(){
    return {
      list:["c","d","e"],
      currentValue: this.value,
      selectedValue: ""
    }
  },
  template:`
    <div>
      <select @change="currentValue = $event.target.value" v-model="selectedValue">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option v-for="item in list" :value="item" :key="item">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  watch:{
    currentValue(newValue){
      if (!this.list.includes(newValue))
        this.selectedValue = "" 

      this.$emit('input', newValue)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    pickedValue: null
  }
})
```

Comment: "_but I can't figure out how can I put HTML in there_" can you explain this with an example like what you want to show and how that suppose to happen using the dropdown?

Comment: When I select a value from the dropdown I want it to show an HTML table, this table should be inside list:["c","d","e"] instead of this letters, but when I do it shows the HTML code, not a table. Maybe this isn't possible or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: may be you can keep the table in parent template only and using `v-if` show them based on select option selected

Comment: What HTML exactly and where does it originate from? It's possible with v-html but is unsafe. Please, explain your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-html` instead. Be careful when using this because if "c", "d", "e" are user inputs, it could expose your application to XSS attacks:

```
    <div id="app">
        <div v-html="pickedValue"></div>
        <picker v-model="pickedValue"></picker>
    </div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html